# Only showing map markers on the last map from a web with multiple maps

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I am working on a web site which includes a list of restaurants.

Each restaurant has a map to show a marker on its location.

I am using following script to show the map for each restaurant:

```
<!--Google map-->
                     
                     <div id="googleMap<?php echo $id ?>" style="width:100%;height:200px;"></div>

                     <script>
                      function myMap<?php echo $id ?>() {
                        var mapProp<?php echo $id ?>= {
                          center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitud?>,<?php echo $longitud?>),
                          zoom:5,
                        };
                        var map<?php echo $id ?> = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap<?php echo $id ?>"),mapProp<?php echo $id ?>);

                        var goldenGatePosition<?php echo $id ?> = {lat: <?php echo $latitud?>,lng: <?php echo $longitud?>};
                        var marker<?php echo $id ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: goldenGatePosition<?php echo $id ?>,
                          map: map<?php echo $id ?>,
                          title: '<?php echo $nombre ?>'
                        });
                      }


                    </script>

                    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.....api key comes here....&callback=myMap<?php echo $id ?>"></script>
```

I have an issue here, then only the last restaurant map is showing the marker. All other restaurants maps are shown, but without the marker.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the last line:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.....api key comes here....&callback=myMap<?php echo $id ?>"></script>
```

You can only do that once.  Either call all the individual callbacks in the one load of the API script or load the API synchronously (without the callback function)

You are probably getting an error in the javascript console about issues loading the API multiple times.

```css
#googleMap1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

#googleMap2 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<!--Google map-->
<!-- New York, NY, USA (40.7127753, -74.0059728) -->
<div id="googleMap1" style="width:100%;height:200px;"></div>

<script>
  function myMap1() {
    var mapProp1 = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.71277532, -74.0059728),
      zoom: 5,
    };
    var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"), mapProp1);

    var goldenGatePosition1 = {
      lat: 40.7127753,
      lng: -74.0059728
    };
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: goldenGatePosition1,
      map: map1,
      title: '$nombre'
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap1);

</script>


<!--Google map-->
<!-- Los Angeles, CA, USA (34.0522342, -118.2436849) -->
<div id="googleMap2" style="width:100%;height:200px;"></div>

<script>
  function myMap2() {
    var mapProp2 = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0522342, -118.2436849),
      zoom: 5,
    };
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"), mapProp2);

    var goldenGatePosition2 = {
      lat: 34.0522342,
      lng: -118.2436849
    };
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: goldenGatePosition2,
      map: map2,
      title: '$nombre'
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap2);

</script>
```